# more tag merging: cameraphones and smartphone

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

I'm pretty sure that [cameraphones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameraphones) and [smartphone](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone) should be the same. There might have been a useful distinction in 2004 but I don't think there is in 2014.

I guess I have a slight preference for [cameraphones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameraphones), but I don't really care which is the master.

Comment: Are we still at the same place now, 4 years later?  I was about to ask this very question, then found yours.  Can we move forward?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: merge [smartphone](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone) into [cameraphones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameraphones). Let [apps](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apps) do the work for phone camera app software.

2 1/2 years on, the [smartphone](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone) and [cameraphones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameraphones) tags are a mess. For the most part, there doesn't seem to be much distinction to the use of the tags.

- There are 49 questions tagged `smartphone`, 58 tagged `cameraphones`, and 9 questions tagged with both.
- Several questions use the word "smartphone", but are only tagged with [cameraphones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameraphones).
- Many questions use terms such as "mobile phone camera", "cellphone camera", or just "phone camera". They are tagged either way, with little distinction.

On a pedantic note, `smartphone` tag is singular, but `cameraphones` is plural. The inconsistency irks me.

- Camera tags that are *technically* adjectives but used as nouns tend to be singular: [dslr](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dslr), [rangefinder](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rangefinder), [mirrorless](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirrorless)
- Tags that are actual nouns tend to be plural: [compact-cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compact-cameras), [old-cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-cameras), [pinhole-cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinhole-cameras)

  - Exceptions proving the rule: [bridge-camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bridge-camera), [instant-camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instant-camera), [wearable-camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wearable-camera)

Comment: Yeah, we are _very_ inconsistent with plural vs. not. There are too many to really clean up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like it if there were a distinction between the two which reflects the documentation we currently have: [cameraphones](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameraphones) is about phones with cameras in, while [smartphone](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone) is more about apps. However, I suspect we're not going to have much luck enforcing that distinction unless "we" (the more active users of the site) re-tag questions as appropriate. That doesn't mean we shouldn't attempt to do it of course.

Comment: I guess I'd rather merge 'em and use tag [tag:apps] for apps. (Or some other more-clearly-mobile-app-oriented tag like (not yet existing) [tag:mobile-apps].

Answer (score -1):

I'd like [smartphone](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartphone) more, since it describes the device better, but [cameraphone](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cameraphone) has the word camera innit. PhotoSE is about cameras, more or less. Then again, there's a camera in just about any mobile phone, but a good deal of photo-applications can only run on smartphones.

I get a feeling, even in 2014, that the next week, if a cameraphone tag gets merged into smartphone, there will come someone complaining over it, saying s/he wanted to ask about the camera of a mobile phone but it ain't no smartphone.

For voting, this answer is **in favor of keeping them as they are.**

Comment: I personally think that there is still a difference, but we may want to clarify or alter the names of the tags.  I think there should be a distinction between phones that can take pictures and software that can be run on a smartphone to work with photos.  I'm not sure exactly how we keep that distinction though.  Perhaps phone-cameras (as opposed to point-and-shoot or system cameras) and smartphone-software.  I'm not sure.

Comment: The cheapest mobile phone I could possibly find last time I was looking for one still had a camera in it.

Answer (score -1):

Since Esa provided a "don't do it", answer, this is the contrary: **we should merge these tags**.